# Why is data binding to canvas not updating UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

[image]I am trying to data bind a collection of lines, and perform a sort function on them and update the UI once the sort has been completed (would like to show the differences in sort algorithms).

I have a basic WPF application which consists of an ItemsControl which is bound to a collection of objects. These objects are bound correctly when the screen is first rendered, however once the sort operation has been completed, the underlying list has been sorted correctly, but the UI has not been redrawn?

Here is my XAML

```xml
<Grid>
   <Button Content="Sort" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="12" MinWidth="80" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="mainControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LineDataTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter" />
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

there is a xaml data template

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="LineDataTemplate">
    <Line X1="{Binding X1}" Y1="{Binding Y1}"
          X2="{Binding X2}" Y2="{Binding Y2}"
          Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="3"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The main data context contains a list of this Line object

```cs
public class Line
{
    public int X1 { get; set; }

    public int Y1 { get; set; }

    public int X2 { get; set; }

    public int Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

And when the datacontext is initialised I create some random lines

```cs
private void RandomiseLines()
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    var startingPoint = 2;

    Values = new List<Line>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Values.Add(new Line() { X1 = startingPoint, Y1 = 420, X2 = startingPoint, Y2 = (420 - rnd.Next(1, 300)) });
        startingPoint += 4;
    }
}
```

Then I have a button on the UI which calls through and (for now) calls a basic sort using linq

```cs
Values = Values.OrderBy(x => x.Y2).ToList();
```

The data context, where this list is held implements the INotifiedProperty changed interface, and once the list is sorted I make a call to the Property changed event. Although the underlying list get sorted the UI does not seem to be redrawing, I have tried using an ObservableCollection and wrapping in Dispatcher but I do not seem to have any binding errors or exceptions being thrown. Can anyone please explain why this does not get updated?

***Edit: Added expected result***
The expected result would be the ItemsControl redrawing itself and the lines would be in the new sorted order

Comment: What is the expected effect of sorting? Wouldn't all Lines still be drawn in the Canvas? What is the purpose of the empty ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: And do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the Values property? I.e. does its setter fire the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the original question, however essentially I wanted the lines to be redrawn in order. Also the DataContext implements the NotifyPropertyChanged interface. Thanks again

Comment: use ObservableCollection instead List

Comment: And does the Values setter fire the PropertyChanged event? With "sorted order" you mean the stacking (i.e. z) order in the Canvas?

Comment: Yes the event is fired after the sorting, however the UI is not updated, thanks

Comment: Also I have tried using an observable collection, and the result is the same. Thanks for the info

Comment: And i am sorting by the Line object Y2 value (in this instance the height of the line)

Comment: We still don't know what "sorted order" in the UI is supposed to mean. You are drawing a bunch of lines with all the same stroke. They are all just draw on top of each other. How would you visually notice their order in the Canvas?

Comment: Sorting the collection doesn't change the actual line coordinates => same coordinates same position => same position no redrawing.

Comment: The order of the collection is not responsible for the drawing. Only the coordinates are relevant for the drawing. There is not relation between sort order and position.

Comment: I have added an image of what i currently have, the aim is to show them being sorted by height. The coordinates are part of the Line object and in  the RandomiseLines function the Y2 property is being set to a random number, this is the value i need to sort by.

Comment: Okay. Then you better use `Rectangle`, because that doesn't rely on coordinates. You just give them the same `Width` but variable `Hight`. The `ItemsPanel` should be a `StackPanel` with the `StackPanel.Orientation` set to `Horizontal`. The `Value` collection must be a `ObservableCollection`. Then it should behave as expected.

Comment: This way the order of the bars will reflect the order of the collection.

Comment: Additionally changed the type of the collection to double. Each value will map to the `Hight` of  a `Rectangle`. Yoiu set apply this mapping via the `DataTemplate` with `TargetType` double.

Comment: Great thanks, will give this a quick try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use `Rectangle` instead of `Line`, because it doesn't rely on coordinates for positioning. You just give them a shared `Width` but a variable `Hight`. The `ItemsPanel` should be a `StackPanel` with the `StackPanel.Orientation` set to `Horizontal`. The Value collection must be a `ObservableCollection<double>`. Then it should behave as expected.
This way the order of the bars will reflect the order of the collection.

**The main view**

```
<StackPanel>
  <Button Content="Sort"
          Click="Button_Click" />
  <ItemsControl x:Name="mainControl"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Values}"
                ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource LineDataTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="LineDataTemplate" DataType="system:Double">
        <Rectangle Width="5" 
                   Height="{Binding}" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   Fill="DarkGray"
                   Margin="0,0,3,0" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

The `Button.Click` event handler

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var viewModel = this.DataContext as TestViewModel;
  var orderedValues = viewModel.Values.OrderBy(value => value).ToList();
  viewModel.Values = new ObservableCollection<double>(orderedValues);
}
```

**The view model**

```
private void RandomiseLines()
{
    var rnd = new Random();

    Values = new ObservableCollection<double>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Values.Add(rnd.Next(1, 300));
    }
}
```